# How to get Current window's "menubar" property using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can we get the Window's "menubar" property value using javascript

Comment: What do you mean by menubar? If it's the browser's then no. This would be a security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers (Safari,Chrome,FF) provide an object `window.menubar` which has an property "visible", but this property doesn't seem to be reliable, it returns **true** for me in FF altough the menubar is hidden.

Comment: Thanks For your reply. I tried with this? It wil not work in ie. But i wonder how so many banking sites have done this.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide / show menu bar with window.open. I guess, most banking site use pop-up to modify the browser toolbars.